# Setting up Snowflake SSO on Excel

Tags: excel, single-sign-on, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried to set up the SSO on Excel to connect to Snowflake.

In the ODBC, I only fill theses fileds :
-data source
-User
-server
-Authenticator : externalbrowser

When I access Excel I choose my ODBC, my browser don't open and I have to enter my user/password.

Please help me to solve this

Thanks
Yassine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to be the right workflow. You need to enter your credentials for the IDP to be able to authenticate you into Snowflake.

I am not sure what is your IDP but below is an example for Azure AD SSO with Excel.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/HOW-TO-connect-to-Snowflake-authenticating-with-Azure-AD-SSO-from-MS-Excel-ODBC-driver

Comment: Hello,
Yes its what's missing, I have to enter my credentials for the first time.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Do you have default browser set up for Excel? If not, then set that and try the steps again.